# ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console

Tags: java, logging, osgi, log4j2, osgi-bundle

I've log4j-api v2.0.2 and log4j-core v2.0.2 in the pom.xml of a fragment project and trying to build a project thats OSGI compliant. I get the following message

```
 "ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. 
    Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the
    console...".
```

log4j2.xml file is under src/main/resources folder. I printed the class path `(System.getProperties())` and both the jar's are loaded in the classpath. Any pointers?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this is a classloader issue with OSGi. Can you create a ticket for this on the log4j2 Jira issue tracker?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-373 I've added a comment here and Matt is following up on this.